# Getting data/geometry from Azure Database into Azure Maps

Tags: geojson, node-js, azure, azure-maps

I'm currently working on a proof-of-concept where we're using an Azure Database as our data storage. I've got one table in there containing a few bits of information, and a geometry column (geometry is all multipolygons).

Now, we'd like to be able to both see and edit these geometries in Azure Maps. From my Googling, it seems that you can't just "hook" the two together - there has to be some intermediary, which is fair enough. I've written a node.js file, currently local on my PC, which can query the data (currently filters on a field, but it'd be easy to send a bounding box).

I guess my question is "what is the recommended way to get Azure Maps and Azure Database talking?" If the preferred method is a node.js, I take it I then need to create a json/geojson from the result and have that displayed in Azure Maps, but how would I go about that? And how would I send/post information back?

I'd also like to stay as clear of Visual Studio as I can, and preferably have a lightweight solution.

Answer (score 1):

To connect a database to one of the Azure Maps interactive map controls, you will need a middle layer to connect the two, typically a rest service. A simple Azure function could be used for this if you want something quick and easy. If you want something a bit more robust, then using Azure Web App service is a good way to go. There is a lot of good resources on developing REST services using either of these. In the REST service itself, if you want to keep things simple, have the data return as GeoJSON and then it can be directly loaded into Azure Maps. Alternatively, if you want you can also have the Well Known Text from the database returned, and then parse it in Azure Maps using the Spatial IO module.

If going the GeoJSON route, I highly recommend using NetTopologySuite as it has libraries for both GeoJSON and SQL spatial data (there is also PostGIS libraries if that's your preference), thus requiring less code to convert between the two, and also providing a good set of tools if you want to do any spatial calculations within the service itself. Alternatively, [CosmosDB supports GeoJSON directly](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-geospatial-intro).

When it comes to requesting data from the database and loading it on the map, there are a lot of approaches that can be taken, and it all depends on the scenario you want to support. For example:

- You could have a search feature that loads one item at a time. So there is limited data being loaded. This is fairly easy to achieve with a simple REST service.
- You could want to download all data in the database. The number and size of the # of coordinates in the shapes can have a big impact in performance. First in the download size, and then in the rendering performance. If you are dealing with 100 thousand or less fairly simple shapes (polygons with 20 or less coordinates on average), you should be able to get good performance by loading everything into the map. If you are dealing with more data, then you will need to optimize how the data is loaded into the map. A common approach is to turn the data into a tile layer. There are raster (image) and vector (raw geometry) based tiles. Raster has been used traditionally, but vector tiles is a newer format that is taking off and likely better suited for your scenario (assuming you are dealing with a very large data set). Going down this path is very complicated currently, but I'm hopeful the Azure Maps Creator platform which is currently focused on indoor maps data, will be expanded to support other spatial data formats. That platform has a dynamic vector tile service for serving your data and also exposes a web feature service for querying the data.

I wrote a paper on this years ago, but haven't had a chance to update it for Azure Maps and newer Azure services (and before vector tiles existed), but lots of good info in there: https://1drv.ms/b/s!AgFqp4QkIjUNloYCwQmwpbyH8dRs6A?e=VvSKje

The code samples for that paper can be found here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgFqp4QkIjUNk9xp2NhhnCKX0RnjnA?e=el2lo3